# Adding/removing classes defined in shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have made a pretty basic web component. I'm adding and removing classes with JavaScript written inside the custom element constructor.

Why is it that when I move the classes from the stylesheet of the document to the stylesheet inside the custom element's shadow DOM, my javascript is no longer able to add or remove them?

```
class BgAnim extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super()

            this.attachShadow({
                mode: 'open'
            })
            this.shadowRoot.innerHTML =
                `
<style>

:host {
background-image: linear-gradient(#0fe0e0 0%, #0fe0e0 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
background-size: 100% 200%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 100%;
padding: 4px;
}
</style>

<span><slot></slot></span>
`

            this.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                this.classList.add('transition')
                this.classList.add('bg-position0')
            })
            this.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
                this.classList.add('bg-position-negative')
                var that = this
                setTimeout(function () {
                    that.classList.remove('transition')
                    that.classList.remove('bg-position0')
                    that.classList.remove('bg-position-negative')
                }, 510)
            })
        }
    }

    customElements.define('bg-anim', BgAnim)
```

The styles that I want to add and remove with my javascript are

```
    .transition {
        transition: background-position .5s ease-in;
    }

    .bg-position0 {
        background-position: 0 0%;
    }

    .bg-position-negative {
        background-position: 0 -100%;
    }
```

When they're in the shadow DOM my JS doesn't work:

```
this.shadowRoot.innerHTML =
                `
<style>
    .transition {
    transition: background-position .5s ease-in;
}

.bg-position0 {
    background-position: 0 0%;
}

.bg-position-negative {
    background-position: 0 -100%;
}

:host {
background-image: linear-gradient(#0fe0e0 0%, #0fe0e0 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
background-size: 100% 200%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 100%;
padding: 4px;
}
</style>
<span><slot></slot></span>
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your styles work in a Shadow DOM, you should use `:host([selector])`:

```
:host(.transition) {
    transition: background-position .5s ease-in;
}

:host(.bg-position0) {
    background-position: 0 0%;
}

:host(.bg-position-negative) {
    background-position: 0 -100%;
}
```

Comment: Also the JS syntax that worked for me was `this.shadowRoot.host.classList.add('my-class');`.

Comment: Relatedly, for applying initial classes you can't do it in the constructor immediately (_*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have attributes*_), but inside e.g. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')`, or in other event handler as the OP already does.